# Route [test.index] not defined?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, dingo-api

I have Dingo API.

This is my routes.php file:

```
Route::resource('test','TestController');

$api = app('api.router');
$api->version('v1',['prefix' => 'api'], function ($api) {
    $api->resource('user', 'App\Http\Controllers\API\v1\UserController');
});
```

In UserController I can only use API routes??

So I cannot do route('test.index') as it gives me this error:
**Route [test.index] not defined**

but route('api.user.index') works fine?

How can I use native Laravel routes like test.index, test.edit etc?

I see route() calling app() function, but I don't get how it works. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Run this command `php artisan route:clear` and then run `php artisan route:list` and look for `test.index` in the result,

Comment: Yes, I find test.index there. If I run php artisan api:routes I get a list of the api routes. It seems like routes() is only calling the API routes instead of laravel routes. I guess somehow Dingo has overridden routes() function to reference only api routes. So how would I access the native Laravel routes found in the route:list ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... The issue was discussed here:
https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/918

A pull request was submitted by jenky https://github.com/dingo/api/pull/919

I simply ran "composer update" to get latest dev version of Dingo API and the issue was solved.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function index() {
    $products = Product::latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('products.index',compact('products'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer.